# How exactly CharBuffer equals() method works?

Tags: java, equals, charbuffer

I cannot understand particular details of `CharBuffer` `equals()` method functioning.

I don't understand this "considered independently of their starting positions" phrase:

> **Two char buffers are equal if, and only if**,
>
> They have the same element type,
>
> They have the same number of remaining elements, and
>
> The **two sequences of remaining elements, *considered independently of
>   their starting positions*, are pointwise equal.**

I studies these good examples - [more examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/charbuffer-equals-method-in-java/), but I don't understand the idea.

Could anyone explain in different words and with minimal insightful example code?

Particularly I find this strange:

```
CharBuffer cb1 = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
cb1.put('a');
cb1.put('b');
//cb1.rewind();
System.out.println(cb1);


CharBuffer cb2 = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
cb2.put(4,'a');
cb2.put(5,'b');
//cb2.rewind();
System.out.println(cb2);

// false, uncommenting rewind() - also false
// but shall be true - "considered independently of starting positions" ?
System.out.println(cb1.equals(cb2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CharBuffer` are compared by what is their **remaining** content. It means that the `equals()` check starts from the **current** buffer position and not from the buffer start. As per [`Buffer.position()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position()):

> A buffer's position is the index of the next element to be read or written. A buffer's position is never negative and is never greater than its limit.

Some methods like `put(char)` will change the buffer position:

```
CharBuffer cb1 = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
cb1.put('a'); // increments position
cb1.put('b'); // increments position

CharBuffer cb2 = CharBuffer.allocate(8);

System.out.println(cb1.equals(cb2)); // true, 00000000 equals 00000000
```

In your example after `cb1.rewind()` the first buffer is `ab00000000` while the second buffer is `0000ab0000`. Calling `cb2.rewind()` is not needed as `put(char, int)` doesn't change the buffer position:

```
CharBuffer cb1 = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
cb1.put((char) 0);
cb1.put((char) 0);
cb1.put((char) 0);
cb1.put((char) 0);
cb1.put('a');
cb1.put('b');
// put(char) increments position so we need to rewind
cb1.rewind(); 

CharBuffer cb2 = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
cb2.put(4, 'a');
cb2.put(5, 'b');

System.out.println(cb1.equals(cb2)); // true, 0000ab0000 equals 0000ab0000
```

Answer (score 3):

> The two sequences of **remaining elements**, **considered independently of their starting positions**, are **pointwise equal**.

1. Only looking at the remaining elements,
2. Without considering where they started,
3. Each element of one buffer must be equal to the **corresponding element** in the other buffer.

In your example, it is the **pointwise equal** part that is important:

```
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
cb1 = a b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
cb1 = 0 0 0 0 a b 0 0 0 0
```

As you can see, when comparing the elements of the char buffer pointwise, they do not match up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that returns `true` for two buffers of differing sizes:

```
CharBuffer cb1 = CharBuffer.allocate(8);
cb1.put('x'); // moves the current position to 1
cb1.put('x'); // moves the current position to 2
cb1.put(2,'a');
cb1.put(3,'b');
System.out.print(cb1);System.out.println ('|');
CharBuffer cb2 = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
cb2.get (); // moves the current position to 1
cb2.get (); // moves the current position to 2
cb2.get (); // moves the current position to 3
cb2.get (); // moves the current position to 4
cb2.put(4,'a');
cb2.put(5,'b');
System.out.print(cb2);System.out.println ('|');
System.out.println(cb1.equals(cb2));
```

`equals` compares the elements in positions 2 to 7 of `cb1` to the elements in positions 4 to 9 of `cb2`, and finds that they are pair-wise equal (both contain the following `char`s - 'a','b',0,0,0,0).

You can see that the starting position is different in the two buffers (2 vs. 4), but the sequences of remaining elements are the same.

```
     0   1   2   3  4   5  6 7 8 9

cb1 'x' 'x' 'a' 'b' 0   0  0 0
             ^
cb2  0   0   0   0 'a' 'b' 0 0 0 0
                    ^
```

When you start comparing the sequences from the starting position, you get two identical sequences.

In your example, you are comparing the sequence 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 (the sequence of remaining elements starts at position 2) to the sequence 0,0,0,0,'a','b',0,0,0,0 (the sequence of remaining elements starts at position 0). Clearly, they are not equal to each other.