# What are CharBuffer objects with different "element type" (not equal by definition)?

Tags: java, equals, charbuffer

The `equals()` method of `CharBuffer` is quite tricky.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022991/how-exactly-charbuffer-equals-method-works) I got that it makes *char-by-char* ( ***or element-by-element ???)*** comparison of the following block: from (starting) position (returned by `position()`) inclusive to `limit()` exclusive. *Capacity and any content before position and after limit is not analyzed in both CharBuffer(s) by equals() method* at all.

But phrases "***same element type***" and "...***elements***... pointwise" beat me.

> Two char buffers are equal [if, and only if](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#equals-java.lang.Object-),
>
> **They have the *same element type*,**
>
> They have the same number of remaining elements, and
>
> The two sequences of remaining **elements**, considered independently of
>   their starting positions, are **pointwise** equal.

What else am I missing?  What is element type? Isn't it always char inside CharBuffer?

P.S. According to implementation code (Java SE8) actually no (element) type check is done within equals(obj) - only standard check `if (obj instanceof CharBuffer)`. So this phrase in API is just for some future implementation or for I-don't-know-what. Or maybe "same element type" just means that equals(arg) - arg must be CharBuffer, which is trivial.

**Could you give an example of two CharBuffer objects with different "element type"?**

Such CharBuffer objects are not equal by definition.

```
CharBuffer cb1 = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
cb1.put('0');
cb1.put('a'); // element type - char ?
cb1.put('b');
cb1.rewind();
cb1.limit(7);
System.out.println(cb1);    

CharBuffer cb2 = CharBuffer.allocate(11);
cb2.put("0ab"); // element type - String ?
cb2.rewind();
cb2.limit(7);
System.out.println(cb2);

// 0ab = 0ab + same number of "empty positions" until limit
// (don't know how to name "empty positions" correctly)
System.out.println(cb1.equals(cb2));  // TRUE
```

Comment: I think you surmised correctly:  “same element type” really means “must be a CharBuffer.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an example of two `CharBuffer` instances with different element types is impossible. The offending comment is not wrong, but it can be inferred from the fact that the element type of `CharBuffer` is always `char`, and it may be seen as redundant.

I can only speculate, but this comment might be meant to clarify that a `ByteBuffer` cannot be equal, even though its content can be viewed as `char` (through the `getChar()`, `putChar()`, and `asCharBuffer()` methods).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very relevant.
If you look into the implementation you can see that no check related to element type is done :

```
public boolean equals(Object ob) {
    if (this == ob) 
        return true;
    if (!(ob instanceof CharBuffer))
        return false;
    CharBuffer that = (CharBuffer)ob;
    if (this.remaining() != that.remaining())
        return false;
    return BufferMismatch.mismatch(this, this.position(),
                                   that, that.position(),
                                   this.remaining()) < 0;
}
```

The single check that is done concerning type is that the object in parameter is an instance of `CharBuffer`.
An interesting thing we can note about it is that  `CharBuffer` derives from `Buffer` but that `CharBuffer` overrides `equals()` in a way where only instance of `CharBuffer`  may be equal between them.
`Buffer` implementations such as `ByteBuffer` or `IntBuffer` are so not interroperable between them.
According to the implementation, it probably means that.
Note that other `Buffer` implementations have similarity about this point :

> They have the same element type

Comment: BufferMismatch.mismatch checks for type.

Comment: @mavriksc It is for Java 11.